# How-to unlink the main Google account from android device without a factory reset

Tags: gmail, google-account, accounts

While setting up my HTC Hero phone, I have entered my gmail account in the setup. But now I want to remove it (I don;t want to change with another account). How do I do it ?

I have searched a lot on Google and everywhere I found that I have to do factory reset but this is not my favoured option.

If there is another way, please let me know.

Comment: A factory reset isn't so bad. I recently did one.

Comment: @AlEverett: a factory reset wipes your data, and if you  have no way to backup it than I wouldn't call it "a good thing".

Comment: Of course it does. Aren't you backing up to the cloud?

Comment: You could try this: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/4570255.
It describes the steps to change the accounts associated with your android phone.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What do you mean,  by 'delete it' exactly? Your phone needs to be linked to a Google account, no matter what (as far as I know). If you do wish to change the "main" Google account your phone is linked with, a factory reset is the way. I've had to do it myself a few times.

If you just want to stop receiving Gmail notifications, go into Settings > Accounts and uncheck the "sync" option for the account you no longer wish to have Gmail sync with.

Comment: Yes, factory reset is the only way to get rid of the main linked Google account to your phone.

Comment: Android devices don't need to be linked with a Google Account..

Comment: @user931 - "Android devices don't need to be linked with a Google Account" If you only want to use it as a phone and you won't be downloading any apps, then you're probably right. But, if you want to be able to go to Google-Play, then I think you do need a Google account.

Answer (score 4):

There are ways to do it without a factory reset.  However, depending upon the phone, it may not work without being linked with a Google account.  I'm not sure about the Hero one way or the other.  See [here](http://www.sizzledcore.com/2009/12/27/how-to-remove-change-google-account-from-android/).

Another option is that you could just create a dummy Google account, then never use it.

Answer (score 3):

Easy! No Factory Reset Needed.. Go to Settings>Accounts&Sync>Then Click the google account you wanna delete(this also applies to the main account)>then press MENU soft key>then Delete Account

That's it!

Comment: That works perfectly.  The MENU button is the little three-square-dots icon in the upper right corner.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Erazzer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/erazzer/dsoft.Erazzer) (requires root).

> This program will be very useful if you want to change main Google account on your Android device without resetting it to defaults preferences. Some features:
>
> - supported on Android 2.x
> - deleting Google accounts (2 methods)
> - accounts backup/restore
> - quick reboot/shutdown
> - widget for quick operations
>
> Warning! Function "reboot in recovery mode" can **delete all data** on some devices, it is disabled by defaults. Don't use it without necessary or if you don't know what is it.

Answer (score 0):

When I pass my phone to other family member, I tried many times to change from my Google  account to another Google account. So far, I know of none, except remove current Google account and then set different Google account. Please note, when you remove the Google account, everything (including all the app) in the phone will be gone, and the phone is reset to factory original condition. Please also note, you can also add another account to your Android. That means your phone will have multiple accounts, but Android always use the first account you entered as default.

To remove Google account:
- settings - Applications - Manage Applications - 
left click - Filter - select filter option - mark "All"
select "google Apps" 
tap "clear data" button
tap "your account must be updated"
now enter your new Google account info.
Reboot.

In another Samsung Galaxy 3 i8700, to reset Google account, all I need is:
- settings - Privacy - 
Under "Personal Data" - Factory Data Reset - erases all data on phone.
You will remove current Google account. Then, re-enter another Google account in:
- settings - Accounts and Sync - "Add Account"

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the password of your Google account using your  laptop and afterwards your Android will scream that he needs the new details and will let you enter a different account

Comment: Are you sure it will scream for username also?