# How can I sign out from gmail in my Android?

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How-to unlink the main Google account from android device without a factory reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2569/how-to-unlink-the-main-google-account-from-android-device-without-a-factory-rese)
>   [Logout from Gmail on my device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18972/logout-from-gmail-on-my-device)

I have a Sony Ericsson Xperia. I have logged in on it with one of my Gmail accounts.
But now I want to change the default gmail account logged in on my phone. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Or possibly [How-to unlink the main Google account from android device without a factory reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2569/981).

Answer (score 2):

Menu button --> Settings --> Accounts and sync--> find your google account there (enter inside)--> remove account...

You cannot remove the account if it is the last google account on your phone, you will have to add a different account before you remove it.