# Delete my Google master account without factory reset?

Tags: google-account

I have three Google accounts configured in my phone. I want to remove my master Google account without losing other important data of my phone.

When I am trying to delete it, it is not allowing me to remove it, as some of the dependent application are installed with that Google account. I tried with removing those application also but still not able to remove it.

Please suggest any solution other than factory reset?

Comment: Since your master google account is the *primary* account, and the only way Android suggests to remove the primary account is by factory resetting. Are you rooted? do you have Titanium Backup? What Android version? What device? Please re-edit your question to include the specifics :) By the way, have you read [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2569/how-to-unlink-the-main-google-account-from-android-device-without-a-factory-rese?rq=1)?

Comment: It should work by deleting cache and data from all related Google apps (Playstore, GSF, GMail, etc.). Though I never tried that, I've read positive reports about that.

Comment: Though its is good @Izzy but your phone will behave like a Factory reset after clearing cache

Comment: @Dr.Andro Definitely not. If you clear cache, all apps and data remain on the device. If you clear cache and data for only the GApps, all other apps remain unaffected. If you do a factory reset, *all* data is gone, and all apps and updates you installed as well. So you see there *is* a difference :)